# Can I call a QObject method from main thread after moveToThread() method is called?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qthread

I have a worker class

```
class Worker(QObject):
    finished = Signal()

    def __init__(self, n):
        super().__init__()
        self.a_flag = False
        # self.mutex = QMutex()

    # @Slot()
    def stop(self):
        self.a_flag = True

    @Slot()
    def do_work(self):
        while True:
            if self.a_flag:
                break
            # do some wo
        self.finished.emit()
```

And somewhere in the controller (from main thread) I am moving it to a new thread

```
self.worker = Worker(num)
self.worker_thread = QThread()
self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)
```

After `self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)` the thread affinity of `worker` is changed and I guess I can't access the members of `worker` in controller (I am not sure about it but I can argue why). Is there any reference that say's anything about it?

Is it safe to do `self.a_flag = True` somewhere in controller (main thread) or call `stop()`?

Is there any workaround to notify `do_work` to get out of the loop?

Comment: "I guess I can't access the members of `worker`" » what makes you think that? As much as any Python attribute, `a_flag` is a public attribute of `worker`, so if you have a reference to `worker`, you can do `worker.a_flag = True`. What you should not do is to access mutable objects from different threads and attempt to change them while both are accessing them (for instance, changing elements of a list), but that's certainly not the case with simple bool flags like yours. OTOH, *connecting* to `stop()` may prevent its call until `do_work` has finished, since the signal may be queued.

Comment: @musicamante Somewhere I read that once you do `self.worker.moveToThread(self.worker_thread)`, you should not touch `worker` object in the thread you made the call.

Comment: @musicamante I am talking about calling `stop` from main thread as a method (not as a slot  connected it to any signal).

Comment: In this specific case, you can safely change the ```worker.a_flag``` member or call the ```worker.stop()``` method()  in the main thread, because currently Python implements a green threading model. If you want to feel safety eagerly, you can use the synchronization APIs, such as the ```threading.Lock``` or ```threading.Condition```.

Comment: @haccks Then just call it. That `a_flag` is just a reference to an bool object, and "setting" it (which is actually overwriting it) is thread safe because it doesn't involve "non atomic operations", and is also not set from multiple threads, at least while they are running. Remember what said above: *access* to members (unless they may be destroyed while running) is always possible, what you should ask is what you do with their values and how thread-safe the operation you're doing should be.

Comment: @musicamante; I agree that access to members is possible. And you right, I am concerned about thread safety. As you mentioned that setting `a_flag` is thread safe, can you provide some reference? I searched a bit and found this [example](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/corelib/threads/queuedcustomtype?h=6.5) from Qt doc. Check the implementation of [`stopProcess()`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/corelib/threads/queuedcustomtype/renderthread.cpp?h=6.5#n69), mutex is used there. They did not set the `m_abort` flag directly.

Comment: @musicamante I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19394348/2455888) suggesting mutex used to protect the variable. But I am not sure how `stop()` will be called? A direct access from main thread?

Comment: @haccks This looks like a case where Practicality Beats Purity. In your specific example, there's no reason to care about thread-safety with respect to `a_flag`. If multiple threads can call `stop`, the order of events will have no effect, since they all set `a_flag` to the same value. It's important to concentrate on the potential *practical* effects on the behaviour of code, rather than on the technical *purity* of a particular solution. The are different levels of thread-safety. If some part of the code isn't thread-safe, the overall results can still be deterministic.

Comment: @musicamante Yes, you are right about bool object.

Comment: @ekhumoro This is funny yet I agree :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I call a `QObject` method from main thread after `moveToThread()` method is called?

Yes.
What thread affinity means *queued events or posted events received by `QObject` will now be handled by new thread (the one where it moved to)*. `moveToThread()` will only change the thread affinity of `worker` (it doesn't really move the object!) and therefore main thread can access `worker`.

Now this raise another question: is it safe to modify `a_flag` in main thread while it is being used by secondary thread?

Yes.

Reason we can set `worker.a_flag` in main thread

- `a_flag` is a *boolean* and setting it is an [*atomic operation*](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe) in python. This makes it thread safe and can be set in main thread
- `a_flag` is always set by one thread (main thread) and read by another.

Also note that **in case of doubt, use mutex**!

```
def __init__(self, n):
    super().__init__()
    self.a_flag = False
    self.mutex = QMutex()

def stop(self):
    self.mutex.lock()
    self.a_flag = True
    self.mutex.unlock()
```

Acquiring lock here not put much overhead, IMO.

Note that if another thread also set boolean variable after reading it
then this operation is not thread safe. Mutex lock is needed in this case. (more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9621288/2455888)]

Comment: ```PyQt``` or ```PySide``` is a wrapper around C++ Qt library. A class derived from the ```QObject``` is just a normal Python class and an instance variable of its instance is also just a normal Python instance variable. So, you shouldn't relate an access to an instance variable to any Qt documentation for C++. Also, it's a bad idea to use the ```QMutex``` instead of the ```threading.Lock```, because it couples a part independent to Qt with a part dependent to Qt, making things more complex.

Comment: Also, just setting(writing) the same variable in two different threads doesn't mean always that it's not thread safe. It depends on the logic or operations.

Comment: @relent95 I know PySide is a wrapper around C++ Qt Library. *you shouldn't relate an access to an instance variable to any Qt documentation for C++. *: Can you explain more?

Comment: *it's a bad idea to use the QMutex instead of the threading.Lock, because it couples a part independent to Qt with a part dependent to Qt, making things more complex.*: can you provide some reference?

Comment: @haccks Qt has absolutely no knowledge of the Python layer: it can only relate to Qt objects, any non-Qt object (including references) created in Python is completely invisible to it, so, the `a_flag` simply does *not* exist for Qt. Things may be a bit different if that flag was a declared Qt property (using the `Property`/`pyqtProperty` functionalities), but that would only *expose* the property to Qt which you'd probably still access through python (property getters/setters are still python functions), the only possible difference would be if access to that property is done directly from Qt.

Comment: @musicamante Does this statement *If you are calling a function on an `QObject `subclass that doesn't live in the current thread [...]* has different meaning in Qt and PySide?

Comment: @haccks You must consider that anything the Qt docs mention is about "its side of things", so, Qt objects (including QObjects), and actual Qt functions. Even if you're using a QObject subclass, any of its methods created in python has absolutely no effect on the Qt side, *unless* it actually interacts with Qt aspects: like a virtual overridden function that can be called by Qt, or anything that may be triggered by events; in fact, your quoting is incomplete: the "and the object might receive events" part you left out is quite important, which is clearly not your case. Events may be sent »

Comment: @haccks » across threads, and QThread alone has its own event loop (unless its `run()` function is overridden) that can receive and handle events on its own. Since events may happen at any time and are normally queued, the result is that functions (including event handlers) may access internal objects indiscriminately, thus making the operation unsafe. Still, as ekhumoro correctly points out, you need to consider practicality over purity, and understand the full context of what the docs explain. You don't use events, you're directly calling a function that doesn't directly interact with Qt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255417/discussion-between-haccks-and-musicamante).

Comment: Good job. Now it's correct.